# Ci4 How to correctly pass data from controller to view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Working backwards, I have a view with the following code;

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <?php 
            // return the value in id 'timezone'
            echo timezone_select('form-control col-6', old('timezone', $user_time_zone->user_setting_value)  );
          ?>
        </div>
```

If `$user_time_zone->user_setting_value` value is set, then no problems.  Some of my users don't have their timezone set, so I need to pass a default timezone.  Here is my controller;

```
        if (empty($this->data['user_time_zone'])){
            $this->data['user_time_zone']->user_setting_value = 'UTC';
        }
        return view('/User_private/Timezone/timezone_update', $this->data);
```

I problem line is `$this->data['user_time_zone']->user_setting_value = 'UTC';`. How can I pass a value to `$user_time_zone->user_setting_value`?  I only want to change the problem line above as there is much more to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can call view as following way

**return view('/User_private/Timezone/timezone_update', ['data' => $this->data]);**